# what is the relationship between Haskell's FreeT and Coroutine type

Tags: haskell, coroutine, conduit, haskell-pipes, free-monad

In the "Coroutine Pipelines" article in [Monad.Reader Issue 19](https://themonadreader.files.wordpress.com/2011/10/issue19.pdf), the author defines a generic `Coroutine` type:

```
newtype Coroutine f m a = Coroutine
  { resume :: m (Either (f (Coroutine f m a)) a)
  }
```

I noticed that this type is very similar to the [`FreeT`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/free-4.12.4/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Free.html#t:FreeT) type from the [`free`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/free) package:

```
data FreeF f a b = Pure a | Free (f b)

newtype FreeT f m a = FreeT
  { runFreeT :: m (FreeF f a (FreeT f m a))
  }
```

It seems that `FreeT` and `Coroutine` are isomorphic.  Here are the functions mapping from one to the other:

```
freeTToCoroutine
  :: forall f m a. (Functor f, Functor m) => FreeT f m a -> Coroutine f m a
freeTToCoroutine (FreeT action) = Coroutine $ fmap f action
  where
    f :: FreeF f a (FreeT f m a) -> Either (f (Coroutine f m a)) a
    f (Pure a) = Right a
    f (Free inner) = Left $ fmap freeTToCoroutine inner

coroutineToFreeT
  :: forall f m a. (Functor f, Functor m) => Coroutine f m a -> FreeT f m a
coroutineToFreeT (Coroutine action) = FreeT $ fmap f action
  where
    f :: Either (f (Coroutine f m a)) a -> FreeF f a (FreeT f m a)
    f (Right a) = Pure a
    f (Left inner) = Free $ fmap coroutineToFreeT inner
```

I have the following questions:

1. What is the relationship between the `FreeT` and `Coroutine` types?  Why didn't the author of "Coroutine Pipelines" use the `FreeT` type instead of creating the `Coroutine` type?
2. **Is there some sort of deeper relationship between free monads and coroutines?**  It doesn't seem like a coincidence that the types are isomorphic.
3. Why aren't popular streaming libraries in Haskell based around `FreeT`?

   The core datatype in [`pipes`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes) is [`Proxy`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-4.3.4/docs/Pipes.html#t:Proxy):

   ```
   data Proxy a' a b' b m r
     = Request a' (a  -> Proxy a' a b' b m r )
     | Respond b  (b' -> Proxy a' a b' b m r )
     | M          (m    (Proxy a' a b' b m r))
     | Pure    r
   ```

   The core datatype in [`conduit`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit-1.2.11) is [`Pipe`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit-1.2.11/docs/Data-Conduit-Internal.html#t:Pipe):

   ```
   data Pipe l i o u m r
     = HaveOutput (Pipe l i o u m r) (m ()) o
     | NeedInput (i -> Pipe l i o u m r) (u -> Pipe l i o u m r)
     | Done r
     | PipeM (m (Pipe l i o u m r))
     | Leftover (Pipe l i o u m r) l
   ```

   I imagine it would be possible to write the `Proxy` or `Pipe` datatypes based around `FreeT`, so I wonder why it is not done?  Is it for performance reasons?

   The only hint of `FreeT` I've seen in the popular streaming libraries is [pipes-group](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-group-1.0.6/docs/Pipes-Group.html), which uses `FreeT` to group items in streams.

Comment: I think the reason the Monad.Reader article and the streaming libraries don't use `FreeT` is the same: it doesn't earn you anything. In the case of the article, I assume the author felt the code was clearer and more self-contained as it appears in the article. In the case of the libraries, why incur a dependency on `free` (and, transitively, a big chunk of the Kmett Platform) when you can get the job done without it? IOW: yes, `FreeT` does support a class of coroutine types but that doesn't mean a given coroutine _must_ be implemented using `FreeT`; boring engineering concerns take precedence

Comment: Thanks @BenjaminHodgson.  I think your comment does a good job of answering my questions 1 and 3.  I'm still wondering about my question 2.  Is there some sort of deeper relationship between coroutines and free monads?

Comment: For question 3, I found an interested comment on reddit by @gabriel-gonzalez (the author of `pipes`): https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/23m4bs/i_added_a_coroutine_example_to_the_wiki_did_i/cgyfxux/ He says that `pipes` is meant to be relatively simple and easy to read.  Along with library usage concerns, that is part of the reason why `pipes` is not using the codensity transformation.  I imagine this could also be part of the reason why it is not based on `FreeT`.  It would be more difficult to understand with no(?) real benefit.

Comment: The `FreeT` construction is actually used by the [`streaming`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming) library.  A [comment](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming-0.2.1.0/docs/src/Streaming-Internal.html#Stream) on the `streaming` library's `Stream` type says that it is equivalent to `FreeT`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To answer your second question, let's first simplify the problem by looking at `Free`. `Free f a` allows you to construct `f`-shaped ASTs of `a`-values for later reduction (aka, interpretation). When comparing the monad transformers in the article with unlifted free constructions, we can simply choose `Identity` for `m`, as is the usual practice for constructing base monads from their transformers: `Free f = FreeT Identity f`.

The Monad Reader article first presents a lifted Trampoline monad transformer, so let's start by looking at the unlifted version, with `Identity` elided:

```
data Trampoline a = Return a | Bounce (Trampoline a)
```

If we compare this to `Free`

```
data Free f r = Pure r | Free (f (Free f r))
```

and squint a bit, we can see that all we really need to do is "remove" the `f`-structure, just as we previously "removed" the `m`-structure. So, we have `Trampoline = Free Identity`, again because `Identity` has no structure. That, in turn, means that this trampoline is a `FreeT Identity Identity`: a sort of degenerate coroutine with trivial shape and no way to use effects to determine whether to bounce or return. So that's the difference between this trampoline and the trampoline monad transformer: the transformer allows the bounces to be interleaved with `m`-actions.

With a bit of work, we can also see that generators and consumers are free monads for specific choices of `f`, respectively `((,) a)` and `((->) a)`. Their free monad transformer versions similarly allow them to interleave `m`-actions (e.g., a generator can ask for user input before yielding). `Coroutine` generalizes both `f`, the AST shape (fixed to `f ~ Identity` for Trampoline) and the type of effects which can be interleaved (fixed to no effects, or `m ~ Identity`) for `Free`. This is exactly `FreeT m f`.

Intuitively, if `Free f` is the monad for pure construction of `f`-shaped ASTs then `FreeT m f` is the monad for constructing `f`-shaped ASTs interleaved with effects supplied by `m`. If you squint a bit, this is exactly what coroutines are: a full generalization that parameterizes a reified computation on both the shape of the constructed AST and the type of effects used to construct it.